Trying to create a live server with Vite and Node.js
I am trying to create an application that hosts a live server, where anyone that connects with it will be able to see any changes made in real time. I am using vite and react.js and I have tried to get it to work for days now. I have used socket.io, express, cors and watched almost any and every youtube video I can find.
I have tried to make my server externally using a server.cjs file:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const cors = require("cors");
const {Server} = require("socket.io")

// Serve static files from the 'src' directory (assuming Vite serves from here)
app.use(cors());

const io = new Server(http, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:5173",
    methods: ["Get", "POST"],
  },
})

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

io.on("connection", (socket) =>{
  console.log(socket.id)  
  socket.on("disconnect", ()=>{
    console.log("User disconnected", socket.id)
  })
})
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
http.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

When I attempted this I always got the message:
GET http://localhost:3001/src/main.jsx net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
I read somewhere that live servers cannot support .jsx files but when I changed it to a .js file I got the same message
I also tried running npm run build, when I tried to open with live server I got the message:
GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/assets/index-gc9qA2yo.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I'm not using React, but these are my NodeJS server settings. Try these modifications:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const path = require('path');

const users = new Map();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/favicon.png', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'favicon.png'));
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(`New connection: ${socket.id}`);
  
  socket.on('add-user', (username) => {
    console.log(`User added: ${username}`);
    users.set(socket.id, username);
    socket.username = username; // Store username on socket object
    io.emit('user joined', { username: username });
    io.emit('update-room', Array.from(users.values()));
  });

  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    const username = users.get(socket.id) || 'Anonymous';
    io.emit('chat message', {
      username: username,
      message: msg.message,
      timestamp: msg.timestamp
    });
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    const username = users.get(socket.id);
    if (username) {
      users.delete(socket.id);
      io.emit('user left', { username: username });
      io.emit('chat message', { username: 'System', message: `${username} has left the chat!`, timestamp: new Date().getTime() });
      io.emit('update-room', Array.from(users.values()));
    }
  });
});

function getSocketByUsername(username) {
  return Array.from(io.sockets.sockets.values()).find(s => s.username === username);
}

server.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3001');
});

I'm running the code using: node server.js
index.html excerpt:
<!-- head -->
    <link href="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
    .neumorphic {
        background: #e0e0e0;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px gray;
    }
    .border {
        border: solid 1px grey;
    }
    .modal {
        transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    @keyframes fadeIn {
        from { opacity: 0; }
        to { opacity: 1; }
    }
    .fade-in {
        animation: fadeIn 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
</style>
    
<!-- body -->
<body class="bg-gray-400 dark:bg-gray-900 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100 transition-colors duration-300">
    <div class="container mx-auto p-4">
        <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row gap-4">
            <div class="w-full md:w-3/4">
                <div class="border neumorphic rounded-lg p-4 mb-4" id="chat-container">
                    <div class="h-96 overflow-y-auto mb-4" id="chatbox">
                        <ul class="space-y-2" id="messages"></ul>
                    </div>
                    <form class="flex" id="chat-form" name="chat-form">
                        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" class="emoji-input border flex-grow mr-2 p-2 rounded-lg bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100">
                        <button class="emoji-picker-button emoji-decor text-white p-2 rounded" style="margin-right:5px;font-size:14pt"></button>
                        <button class="send-btn bg-blue-800 hover:bg-blue-400 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-lg transition duration-300">Send</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
    <div class="modal fixed inset-0 bg-gray-600 bg-opacity-50 hidden items-center justify-center" id="username-prompt">
        <div class="neumorphic bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 rounded-lg p-4 w-full max-w-sm">
            <p>Please choose a username:</p>
            <input class="flex-grow mr-2 p-2 rounded-lg bg-white dark:bg-gray-700" id="username" required="" type="text"><br>
            <input class="mr-2" id="save-username" type="checkbox"> <label for="save-username">Remember me</label><br>
            <button class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-lg transition duration-300 mt-2" id="set-username">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.js"></script>

<!-- js -->
        <script>
            var socket = io();
            var room = [];

            function setCookie(name, value, days) {
                const d = new Date();
                d.setTime(d.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                const expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
                document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
            }

            function getCookie(name) {
                const nameEQ = name + "=";
                const ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                    let c = ca[i];
                    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
                }
                return null;
            }

        function setUsername() {
            var username = $('#username').val();
            if (username.trim() !== '') {
                if ($('#save-username').is(':checked')) {
                    setCookie('username', username, 365); // Save for 1 year
                }
                $('#username-prompt').remove();
                socket.emit('add-user', username);
            }
        }

        $(function () {
            let username = getCookie('username');
            if (!username) {
                $('#username-prompt').removeClass('hidden').addClass('flex');
                $('#set-username').click(function () {
                    setUsername();
                });
                $('#username').on('keydown', function (e) {
                    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                        setUsername();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                socket.emit('add-user', username);
            }

                socket.on('user joined', function (data) {
                    $('#messages').append($('<li>').html(formatMessage({
                        from: 'System',
                        message: `${data.username} has joined the chat!`,
                        timestamp: new Date().getTime()
                    })).addClass('fade-in'));
                    scrollToBottom('#chatbox');
                    playSound(joinSound);
                });

                socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
                    $('#messages').append($('<li>').html(formatMessage(msg)).addClass('fade-in'));
                    scrollToBottom('#chatbox');
                    playSound(messageSound);
                });

                $('#chat-form').submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var message = $('#m').val();
                    if (message.trim() !== '') {
                        socket.emit('chat message', {
                          message: message,
                          timestamp: new Date().getTime()
                        });
                        $('#m').val('');
                    }
                });
        </script>

I'm not sure if that will be of any assistance, but it can't hurt.

What does your index.html look like?

Hi, Is the issue still persisting ?

@BrysonSutton I'm sorry man, I just saw the comment, I'm way late. My index.html is huge, it's a chat room application with private messaging and voice calls.  But here is the relevant part as far as username and socket connection.
